# Terraform - How do I reference my Output inside on of my modules?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Having trouble trying to reference one of my outputs in main.tf. I'm trying to use an output of a public IP address of an instance to try and connect to it using `remote-exec` . Here are the files:

main.tf

```
module "subnetwork" {
  source = "../modules/uc1" 
  env                   = "${var.var_env}"
  company               = "${var.var_company}"
  depends_on = [
    module.vpc
  ]

}

output "server_private_ip" {
  value = google_compute_instance.default.network_interface[0].network_ip
}

output "server_public_ip" {
  value = google_compute_instance.default.network_interface[0].access_config[0].nat_ip
}
```

../modules/uc1:

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {
  name         = "${format("%s","${var.company}-${var.tester}-${var.env}-${var.var_region_name}-instance1")}"
  machine_type = "${var.var_machine_type}"
  zone         = "${var.var_zone_name}"

  tags = ["http", "https", "ssh"]

  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "${var.var_instance_image}"
    }
  }


  metadata = {
    ssh-keys = "root:${file(var.var_ssh)}"
  }

    
  provisioner "remote-exec" {

    connection {
    user = "root"
    host = module.uc1.server_public_ip <--- here is the error
    type     = "ssh"
    private_key = "${file(var.var_ssh)}"
  }

    script = "./scripts/nginx_instance.sh"
  }

  network_interface {
    subnetwork = "${google_compute_subnetwork.public_subnet.name}"
    access_config {
      // Ephemeral IP
    }
  }

}
```

The issue im having is trying to reference my output public IP address in `remote-exec`:

```
  provisioner "remote-exec" {

    connection {
    user = "root"
    host = module.uc1.server_public_ip
    type     = "ssh"
    private_key = "${file(var.var_ssh)}"
  }

    script = "./scripts/nginx_instance.sh"
  }
```

Here is the error:

```
│   on ..\modules\uc1\instance.tf line 24, in resource "google_compute_instance" "default":  
│   24:     host = module.uc1.server_public_ip
│
│ No module call named "uc1" is declared in module.subnetwork.
```

Answer (score 7):

The module name is `subnetwork` not `uc1`. `uc1` is the name of the folder the module's source files are in. When you declared the module: `module "subnetwork" {` you named it "subnetwork". To reference it would be:

```
host = module.subnetwork.server_public_ip
```

Assuming you declared an output named `server_public_ip` inside the module.